# ArrayAdapter is not working with ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

Now im trying to create my first Android app.
I'm currently working on a view name Bands which is supposed to create a list (imported from Firebase Database) and link it to a ListView.
As you can see, i have a link to print out the whole bandsList, that way i know the list imported well, and it is...but the ListView is not updated according to the bandsList, so im guessing the problem is in the adapter.

```
   public class Bands extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String>  bandsList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> bandsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bands);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.bandsListView);
        bandsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, bandsList);
        listView.setAdapter(bandsAdapter);

        final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Bands");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot band : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String bandName = band.child("Name").getValue(String.class);

                    bandsList.add(bandName);
                    System.out.println("bandsList :" + bandsList);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


            }
        });
        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                //String BandName =dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                for (DataSnapshot band : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String bandName = band.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                    System.out.println(bandName);
                    bandsList.add(bandName);
                    System.out.println(bandsList);}

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the bandsList ListView is empty.
The app is working with no errors but the list is not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add bandsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after the Firebase-Callback:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot band : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String bandName = band.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
        bandsList.add(bandName); 
        System.out.println("bandsList :" + bandsList);
    }
    bandsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the adapter to update the list in both
 onDataChange() and onChildAdded() using  bandsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();